# Run a command line on a web remote PC

Tags: command-line, msbuild, remote-access

Assuming that I can install apps on the remote PC configure the firewall rules and ports, what whould be the easiest and most secure way to fit the following requirements:

1. I want to send command lines commands to the destination computer from my msbuild script
2. Would be nice. The destination computer sends echo of its command execution to the client computer

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx ?

Comment: that or use powershell remoting.